# Best way to enable/disable navigation items in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My project is a site with multiple sub pages. You should use the website like this:

- Page 1: Choose some elements from a list. Save your selection.
- Page 2: For each element you've chosen, set two parameters. Press on a button in order to calculate a score.
- Page 3: Choose from three different options to export your result.

The navigation bar contains links to these sub pages.

I'd like to enable/disable the navigation items based on the user's progress. For example, you shouldn't be able to reach the export page if you haven't visited the other two pages previously.

At the moment I try to do it like this: I enable/disable the items based on the content of localStorage (more precisely the existence of an array. this is what I use to save the user's selection on page 1). This works pretty good, but I have one problem: If I leave the page and come back some time later, the array is still in the localStorage, which means that all menu items are enabled. I could delete on the last page, but what if the user tries to re-visit a previous page to modify his input?

Is there a better way to do this?

Greetings

Comment: Could [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) work better for you?

Comment: You could add a timestamp to the array. If the last update to the timestamp was like more than 5 mins ago, delete the array from storage. Or you could do the same thing with some kind of token attached to the URL. Or you could check the history to see from which page you're coming previously. etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the help of jquery:

put condition according to your `local storage` and apply the following code:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#item").attr("disabled", "true");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the user the option to start a new progression (something like a button that clears the array) and that way to let him decide if he wants to change the previous progression or start a new one.